# Azure function- Failed to generate proxies for remote module 'AzureAD'

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, azure-functions

I am using the following to add in the AzureAD

```
Import-Module AzureAD -UseWindowsPowerShell
```

I have also added in `'AzureAD' = '2.*'` in the requirements.psd1

Yet when I run the function I am getting the following error message:

ERROR: Failed to generate proxies for remote module 'AzureAD'. The -OutputModule parameter does not resolve to a path, and a user module path cannot be found for the provided name.Exception             :Type           : System.InvalidOperationExceptionMessage        : Failed to generate proxies for remote module 'AzureAD'. The -OutputModule parameter does not resolve to a path, and a user module path cannot be found for the provided name.InnerException :Type           : System.Management.Automation.CmdletInvocationExceptionErrorRecord    :Exception             :Type       : System.ArgumentExceptionMessage    : The -OutputModule parameter does not resolve to a path, and a user module path cannot be found for the provided name.TargetSite :Name          : ThrowTerminatingErrorDeclaringType : System.Management.Automation.MshCommandRuntime, System.Management.Automation, Version=7.2.4.500, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35MemberType    : MethodModule        : System.Management.Automation.dllSource     : System.Management.AutomationHResult    : -2147024809StackTrace :at System.Management.Automation.MshCommandRuntime.ThrowTerminatingError(ErrorRecord errorRecord)TargetObject          : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ExportPSSessionCommandCategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (Microsoft.PowerShel…ortPSSessionCommand:ExportPSSessionCommand) [Export-PSSession], ArgumentExceptionFullyQualifiedErrorId : ExportPSSession_ErrorModuleNameOrPath,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ExportPSSessionCommandInvocationInfo        :MyCommand       : Export-PSSessionHistoryId       : 1InvocationName  : Export-PSSessionCommandOrigin   : InternalScriptStackTrace      : at , C:\home\site\wwwroot\TimerTrigger1\run.ps1: line 3TargetSite     :Name          : InvokeDeclaringType : System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PipelineBase, System.Management.Automation, Version=7.2.4.500, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35MemberType    : MethodModule        : System.Management.Automation.dllMessage        : The -OutputModule parameter does not resolve to a path, and a user module path cannot be found for the provided name.InnerException :Type       : System.ArgumentExceptionMessage    : The -OutputModule parameter does not resolve to a path, and a user module path cannot be found for the provided name.TargetSite :Name          : ThrowTerminatingErrorDeclaringType : System.Management.Automation.MshCommandRuntime, System.Management.Automation, Version=7.2.4.500, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35MemberType    : MethodModule        : System.Management.Automation.dllSource     : System.Management.AutomationHResult    : -2147024809StackTrace :at System.Management.Automation.MshCommandRuntime.ThrowTerminatingError(ErrorRecord errorRecord)Source         : System.Management.AutomationHResult        : -2146233087StackTrace     :at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PipelineBase.Invoke(IEnumerable input)at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.Pipeline.Invoke()at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Worker.ConstructPipelineAndDoWork(Runspace rs, Boolean performSyncInvoke)at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.CoreInvokeHelper[TInput,TOutput](PSDataCollection`1 input, PSDataCollection`1 output, PSInvocationSettings settings)at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.CoreInvoke[TInput,TOutput](PSDataCollection`1 input, PSDataCollection`1 output, PSInvocationSettings settings)at System.Management.Automation.RemoteDiscoveryHelper.InvokeNestedPowerShell(PowerShell powerShell, PSCmdlet cmdlet, PSInvocationSettings invocationSettings, String errorMessageTemplate, CancellationToken cancellationToken)+MoveNext()at System.Management.Automation.RemoteDiscoveryHelper.EnumerateWithCatch[T](IEnumerable`1 enumerable, Action`1 exceptionHandler)+MoveNext()HResult        : -2146233079CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Import-Module], InvalidOperationExceptionFullyQualifiedErrorId :

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the same error:***

[image]

I created a Function App with **configuration settings** like below:

[image]

***To resolve the error, make sure to set the **Runtime version as `4`** like below:***

[image]

I added **`'AzureAD' = '2.*'`** in the ***requirements.psd1*** file:

[image]

I created **Http trigger function** and got the module imported successfully like below:

```
using namespace System.Net
param($Request, $TriggerMetadata)
Import-Module -Name 'AzureAD' -UseWindowsPowershell
Push-OutputBinding -Name Response -Value ([HttpResponseContext]@{
StatusCode = [HttpStatusCode]::OK
Body = $body
})
```

**Response:**

[image]

If still the error persists, try creating a new Function App from scratch with **latest versions**.

Alternatively, you can also invoke the Http trigger **multiple times** to get the response successfully.

**Reference:**

[Azure function - import module error by MayankBargali-MSFT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/920865/azure-function-import-module-error.html)